# Error during compilation

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I downloaded a software framework from the Data Prefetching Championship website (http://www.jilp.org/dpc/) and installed on a computer with the Ubuntu OS, 64 bit.  I followed all of the instructions for unpacking the compressed file, and entered the "make" command to compile and this is what I received:

```
g++ -Wl,-u,main -g -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--version-script=/grads/hhoffman/Documents/ELE_591/PREF_KIT/pin-2.5-22247-gcc.4.0.0-ia32_intel64-linux/source/include/pintool.ver -L/grads/hhoffman/Documents/ELE_591/PREF_KIT/pin-2.5-22247-gcc.4.0.0-ia32_intel64-linux/Lib/ -L/grads/hhoffman/Documents/ELE_591/PREF_KIT/pin-2.5-22247-gcc.4.0.0-ia32_intel64-linux/ExtLib/ -L/grads/hhoffman/Documents/ELE_591/PREF_KIT/pin-2.5-22247-gcc.4.0.0-ia32_intel64-linux/extras/xed2-intel64/lib -L/grads/hhoffman/Documents/ELE_591/PREF_KIT/pin-2.5-22247-gcc.4.0.0-ia32_intel64-linux/intel64/lib -L/grads/hhoffman/Documents/ELE_591/PREF_KIT/pin-2.5-22247-gcc.4.0.0-ia32_intel64-linux/intel64/lib-ext  -o bin/CMPsim.usetrace ./bin/libCMPsim64.a ./src/prefetch/sample_prefetcher.o -lpin  -lxed -ldwarf -lelf -ldl  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a(gzio.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [CMPsimpref64] Error 1
```

The problem, I believe, is with the libz.a file.  Help?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the folks running the competition? I'm sure they will have seen this before and have specific instructions, though you may have to explicitly ask for them. Other than that, the error message is telling you specifically which flags need to be added when building the library to make it linkable in your environment -- or you could try asking for the source code for the library and building it locally, which will increase the odds of your having a version that links happily with your own code.

Comment: why you are passing the direct path of `libz.a`? How about using `-lz` instead of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a`?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how you compile this application, but you should add `-fPIC` to the compilation flags (CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS) of C/C++ files and recompile the application.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem mentions above but I am able to solved it with **scientific linux 5.4** with **gcc 4.1** configuration and I did one mistake when we have to set path up to prefetch kit. There was **'$'** sign which we have to remove while setting path for that PREF_KIT